# Is it possible to control the JSONB serialization?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I would like to export a [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html) column in a Postgres (v9.6) table.

I tried the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) command:

```
\COPY (SELECT my_json_column FROM my_table) to 'data.json';
```

I did get a JSON file, but I would like two modifications:

1. I want to conserve space: no spaces after delimiters `:` and `,`.
2. I want a uniform and predictable key sorting.

In other words, I want the behavior of the Python [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) with arguments

1. `separators=(',',':')`
2. `sort_keys=True`

(This is the format of the ingested file, and I want to export it in the same format to check that the roundtrip is identity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in options to format jsonb output. You can use [PL/Python.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html)

```
create extension if not exists plpython3u;
```

As for now (Postgres 10) you have to use [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to convert Postgres jsonb to a Python object (automatic conversion will be possible in future releases).

```
create or replace function format_jsonb(obj jsonb)
returns text language plpython3u as $$
    import json
    import ast
    js = ast.literal_eval(obj);
    return json.dumps(js, separators=(',', ':'), sort_keys=True)
$$;
```

Use:

```
select format_jsonb('{"abcd": 1, "jklm": 2, "jkl": 3, "abc": 4}');

            format_jsonb             
-------------------------------------
 {"abc":4,"abcd":1,"jkl":3,"jklm":2}
(1 row)
```

So your command may look like this:

```
\COPY (SELECT format_jsonb(my_json_column) FROM my_table) to 'data.json';
```

Comment: This should work in every supported version of Postgres. I mentioned Postgres 10 in the sense: now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve your original format, don't use `jsonb`. Use `json` which stores the value as you input it. Even with the output massage you envision, duplicate keys would be lost.

If you need `jsonb` facilities, cast the column to `jsonb` on the fly. You can still be efficient, because you can add an index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytab USING gin ((jsoncol::jsonb));
```

Comment: I don't care about duplicate keys, I don't have them. All I care about is the key order and spaces after separators.